# SQL advanced sub select query

Tags: sql

I would like to expand on this simple sub select:

```
Select * from table1 where pkid in (select fkid from table2 where clause...)
```

The logic above is fairly simple - get me all rows in table1 where the pkid is contained in the subset returned from the sub select query that has a where clause. It works well because there is only 1 field being returned.

Now I want to expand on this.

In table 1 I want to return results where field1 and field2 and field3 in select (field1, field2, field3 from table2 where clause...)

How is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Example.

**TABLE1**

```
FIELD1  FIELD2 FIELD3    
1       2      3    
2       3      4     
4       5      6
```

**TABLE 2**

```
2       3      4 
4       5      6
```

I want to return 2 results.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand what you need you can try:

```
SELECT t1.field1, t1.field2, t1.field3 FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.field1 = t2.field1
   AND t1.field2 = t2.field2
   AND t1.field3 = t2.field3
   AND t2.... // Use this as WHERE condition
```

Comment: Yeah sorry if the question was hard to understand. But I think you've nailed it.

Answer (score 1):

Like Marco pointed out, what you want to do is an `INNER JOIN`.

But (that's just FYI, you should definitely use Marco's solution) it's also possible to simply use braces.

```
Select * 
from table1 
where (field1, field2, field3) in (select field1, field2, field3 from table2 where clause...)
```

At least in MySQL (wasn't this question tagged with MySQL?)

Comment: That assumes alot.  ORACLE can do this, SQL SERVER can not, for example.

Comment: @Dems: it is valid standard SQL, which is surely acceptable if the question just has the `sql` tag.

Comment: @onedaywhen - The quote `At least in MySQL (wasn't this question tagged with MySQL?)` was added after my comment. Without that addition the answer implies it works in all versions of SQL, which is false.

Comment: @Dems: did you mean to say **all versions of SQL**? How would you go about testing/proving that a SQL statement satisfied that condition? Assuming you cannot, I would say that posting EITHER proprietary code with a declaration of product and version OR standard SQL (preferable with an appropriate declaration) is acceptable.

Comment: @onedaywhen - There is no implementation of `standard SQL` and the answer *at the time of my comment* did not specify which version of SQL it does or does not work in. I don't feel that drawing attention to the fact that *it only works in certain implementations* is a bad comment. It even prompted the poster of the answer to add a comment to clarify the details. I'm not sure why this is so contentious; the answer was short of relevant information, I drew attention to that, the answer was updated to reflect that. It all seems productive, up to that point...

Comment: @Dems: The posted code assumes the OP's SQL product has implemented the row value comparison feature of standard SQL (we can add PostgreSQL to the list of commonly used SQL products that do). You think that amounts to 'alot', I do not, no big deal. I don't mean to imply your comment is 'bad', apologies if you took offence.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a temporary table

```
select field1, field2, field3 into #tempTable from table2 where clause...

select * from table 1 
where filed1 in (select field1 from #tempTable)
and filed2 in (select field2 from #tempTable)
and filed3 in (select field3 from #tempTable)
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using `IN` for most cases like this.  It's very limitting.

I prefer to use a JOIN in most cases.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT c1, c2, c3 FROM anotherQuery) AS filter
    ON  yourTable.c1 = filter.c1
    AND yourTable.c2 = filter.c2
    AND yourTable.c3 = filter.c3
```

(Ensure the filter returns unique combinations of `c1, c2, c3` using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` if necessary)

Answer (score 0):

you didn't mentioned engine, so I'll assume SQL Server.
This query will show you what's on both tables

```
select FIELD1, FIELD2 from table1 
intersect
select FIELD1, FIELD2 from table2
```